# What is different between .dat and .txt files in python?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

in this code why he used .dat file and didn't use .txt file
known that i tried it using .txt file and it worked perfectly .
and why the access mode in that way also the information is stored as text not in binary.

```
import pickle

print("Pickling lists.")
variety = ["sweet", "hot", "dill"]
shape = ["whole", "spear", "chip"]
brand = ["Claussen", "Heinz", "Vlassic"]
f = open("pickles1.dat", "wb")
pickle.dump(variety, f)
pickle.dump(shape, f)
pickle.dump(brand, f)
f.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean "the information is stored as text not in binary"? That program stores the data in binary if you run it on Python 3, although it uses a non-binary format in Python 2. Here's the Python 3 contents as a `bytes` string: `b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x00sweetq\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00hotq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00dillq\x03e.\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x00wholeq\x01X\x05\x00\x00\x00spearq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00chipq\x03e.\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x08\x00\x00\x00Claussenq\x01X\x05\x00\x00\x00Heinzq\x02X\x07\x00\x00\x00Vlassicq\x03e.'`

Comment: And here's the Python 2 version: `"(lp0\nS'sweet'\np1\naS'hot'\np2\naS'dill'\np3\na.(lp0\nS'whole'\np1\naS'spear'\np2\naS'chip'\np3\na.(lp0\nS'Claussen'\np1\naS'Heinz'\np2\naS'Vlassic'\np3\na."`

Comment: how did you get that result? @PM2Ring

Comment: I added this to the end of your code: `with open("pickles1.dat", "rb") as f: print(repr(f.read()))`

Answer (score 2):

the extension doesn't tell the contents.

Program author used .dat so you cannot open it (easily) with a text editor and see or even change the apparent garbage inside (which is partly ASCII, and partly non-ASCII) which would destroy/corrupt the data.

As long as you open the file in binary, any file "type" will work. Opening in text mode can "corrupt" the file in some cases of line-termination conversion (happens a lot on windows)

Note that pickle is not the best choice when you're dumping native python structures such as lists and dictionaries. In that case, you're better off with `json` format, which requires text mode, and has the nice advantage to be readable and even editable as long as you respect the original structures.

Comment: how can .dat file stop me from editing it or see it . i open it with notepad and i can delete it .  another thing when i open the write_it.dat file i don't understand what is written it gave something like that """€]q (X   sweetqX   hotqX""" can you clarify this to me i'm still a noobie.

Comment: you _can_ edit/view it in notepad but that's not the built-in file association like .txt. The .dat file isn't made to be readable, as opposed to json format.

Comment: The choice between pickle and json is not that clear cut to be frank. The only real advantage of using json is that it is human readable - which may not be desirable in some cases. The benefit of pickle is that it can exactly recreate the Python structure - where as json can't reproduce types like tuples (or dictionaries with tuples as keys). Unless you know that your data is simple with no tuples, complex values, Decimals, Fractions etc then pickle is better.